# Can I use Bisquick instead of All Purpose Flour?

Tags: baking

Can I use Bisquick instead of All Purpose Flour?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [se] and [cooking.se]. When posting, you'll get a speedy answer in most cases -- regardless of urgency! Please also describe the substitution you're trying to make -- e.g., in what application (e.g., pancakes, loaf bread, pie crust, ...) or recipe to you need to make this substitution?

Comment: There might be a few places where you could get away with it (eg, as part of a three-step breading), but they'd be exceptions, not norms.

Comment: Yes, you can use Bisquick instead of flour, when making macaroni and cheese. It came out perfect (the roux).

Answer (score 15):

**You *cannot* directly use Bisquick in place of AP flour.**

According to the company web site and Wikipedia, [Bisquick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisquick#Ingredients) consists of bleached all-purpose flour with several other ingredients, including *fat (shortening), leavening (baking powder), sugar, and salt*. It is essentially a [self-rising flour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flour#Self-rising_flour) with added fat. Because of all of the extra ingredients, it will not behave the same as regular all-purpose flour.

Depending on the recipe or application, you may be able to substitute or remove some of the other ingredients to make use of a pre-mixed flour like Bisquick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sometimes you can use Bisquik instead of flour. I rarely cook, but I had been ending up with overripe bananas fairly often so I decided to make banana bread. I thought the container in the top shelf of the cupboard was flour. After making four batches of banana bread and one of zucchini bread over a couple of months, the container of flour was almost empty. That's when I found the back of the Bisquik box under the container. I had been using Bisquik all along, thinking it was flour. (I told you I rarely cook! I remember now I bought Bisquik to make pancakes eons ago.) All the bread turned out great. I took it to work, where it quickly disappeared, so that's more than just my opinion. So maybe sometimes you can't just substitute Bisquik for flour, but sometimes a 1:1 substitution works just fine. In fact, I'm a little leery of using real flour next time! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I had made scones. I wasn't sure it was going to work with the Bisquick powder but it came out great. I put all the ingredients needed plus the Bisquick powder. Although in some recipes it may not work, so just be mindful.