# Can selfriseing flour be used in placeof bisquet mix?

Tags: baking

I want to make sesame sticks the recipe calls for 2 cups of bisque mix  can I use self riseing flour in place of the bisque mix?

Comment: Maybe. But in order for us to give an answer, we need to know the recipe you are using and the ingredients in your biscuit mix. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Bisquick instead of All Purpose Flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61892/can-i-use-bisquick-instead-of-all-purpose-flour)

Comment: @Sobachatina : actually, this one's easier, as you're trying to replace something with *more* ingredients in it, so you just have to add fat and salt (and maybe adjust baking powder), rather than adjust to recipe to remove then as separate additions.

Comment: This is the opposite question. @Sobachatina :D