# Substituting pancake mix for flour

Tags: substitutions, cake, flour

Can I use pancake mix (just whole wheat flour and baking powder ingredients) instead of regular flour to make a cake? (I have a recipe for whole wheat chocolate cake). Would I just leave out the baking powder or add less baking powder? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's all that is in your pancake mix? You normally have some baking soda, baking powder, oils, salt, sugar, corn starch in there (You'll find all of these in Bisquick, plus some conditioners to make the gluten stronger and things like that). Possibly some egg and milk products depending on the type of mix.

Even if that's all the stuff in your baking mix, you don't necessarily know how much baking powder is in there to compensate for in your recipe (you may need to add more or the pancake mix may have too much leavener). Too much baking powder can affect texture (not structurally sound enough) and flavor (bitterness).

That being said, you may want to experiment. Some recipes will take better to substitution of the pancake mix than others. See also [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61892/can-i-use-bisquick-instead-of-all-purpose-flour/61894).

However, if you have only one shot at the recipe (or don't want to deal with the possible wastage of ingredients), go buy the appropriate flour. And then use the pancake mix for pancakes (or not great waffles; despite the marketing spiel on the box, pancake mix makes for OK pancakes and bad waffles).

Comment: Yes, it's very simple mix with no oils, sugar, milk or corn starch. Just a bit of salt as well as the baking powder ingredients.

Comment: Are you saying Bisquick makes bad waffles? If so any recommendations? (possibly needs to be another question)

Comment: @user3169 - yes. See alton brown's good eats episode on waffles, for example.  You need a different amount of fat and sugar; I guess good starting points would be the waffle recipes by Bravetart on seriouseats.com.

Comment: @padma - unfortunately, with the added salt, you can't calculate the amount of baking powder added (since both will be in the sodium). but you can probably make a guess at how much baking powder and salt there is by looking up a few pancakes recipes from scratch using whole wheat flour and getting a consensus from how much salt and baking powder they add for the recipe. That'll give you an idea of how much to adjust the salt and baking powder should you try to make the cake with the mix.

Comment: @Batman I'll try to find it online. I cut the cord years ago so no Food Network TV anymore.

Comment: @user3169 - The Good Eats books might have something (my copy is in storage, unfortunately). The transcript is [here](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season9/waffles/waffle_tran.htm) , but I guess it doesn't add much to what I said before. But basically, when you buy something like Bisquick, you're compromising for the range of things you can use it for. It isn't going to do as well as a specialized batter for each waffles and pancakes. Try comparing his waffle recipe (prev. link) to his [pancake recipe](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season3/pancakes/pancakestranscript.htm).